"Unsupported OS" while connecting to docker container
I am using a Windows host with vscode (v1.92.2) and connecting via remote-SSH extension and with dev-containers extension (v0.380.0) to a docker container, running on another Linux machine.
The docker image is a custom Linux-based build environment, and while connecting to it I get the following error message from vscode:

You are about to connect to an OS version that is unsupported by Visual Studio Code

The docker image is a Linux build, that has apt.
So, as suggested by someone, I tried to install tar, curl, wget and the installation worked.
This did not solve the issue.
I also found these requirements for the "Remote host ...":
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux
but it is not clear which glibc they mean, the one of the remote host or the one inside the docker image.
I have:

Linux host glibc: 2.31;
docker image glibc: 2.23.

Does it mean, dev-containers are incompatible with my docker image?

Considering that you have a problem, and one glibc that's too old (2.23 < 2.28), the logical conclusion is indeed to fix that.

That's what I was afraid of, in view of how complex it usually is to update glibc Version with everything that depends on it. It like creating a whole new docker from scratch.

@Student4K: One of the key advantages of Docker is how easy it is to create new docker images from "scratch". That's what Dockerfiles are for. You're not supposed to hand-assemble them.

The complexity comes from creating a stable and functioning SW distribution, with proper component Versions, Patches etc. Packaging them together, i.e. what docker does, is Just a tiny fraction of that complexity.
